# Gecko browser different proxies and cookies

Tags: gecko

I need to access several sites simultaneously in my gecko-based browser, under different proxies and cookies. 
Problem is that you can only setup cookies/proxies for entire gecko browser class, not for separate objects of it.
Is there any workaround?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "gecko browser class". Is this a browser you built yourself using the Mozilla libraries? Also, cookies are stored per site, so I don't see how they can be a problem, unless your browser is very different from the standard...

Comment: I mean that proxies are applied to gecko via some static fields, so if you open site1 with proxy1, and then in other process open site2 with proxy2, proxy2 will be applied to further work with site1.

Comment: And for cookies I need to be able to open same site in different threads with different cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a separate application with browser for each site I need to open, but its ugly.